# How to visuzlize facebook post

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api

I have a post id (obtained from the Graph API), can I generate a URL which will display this post in Facebook's interface?

Seems there should be something like http://facebook.com/viewpost?postid=6666666666 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to manually construct a permalink given only the post ID?

The Graph API for a post ID returns the URLs the user should go to to comment on or like the post, assuming the viewing user has permission to do so.

Example:
`GET http://graph.facebook.com/19292868552_10150189643478553?access_token={access token here}`

Snipped some of the fields of the response, but you're looking for 'actions':

```
{
  "id": "19292868552_10150189643478553", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Facebook Platform", 
    "category": "Product/service", 
    "id": "19292868552"
  }, 

  // removed fields from response

  "actions": [
    {
      "name": "Comment", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/19292868552/posts/10150189643478553"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Like", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/19292868552/posts/10150189643478553"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Share", 
      "link": "http://networkedblogs.com/hGWk3?a=share"
    }
  ], 
  // Snipped rest of response
```

In general, the format of a permalink seems to be:
`https://www.facebook.com/{source id}/posts/{post object id}`
(Source ID being the user or page ID where the post is)

You can't definitely reply on that URL format always being the same; the API response should be always accurate though